# GROUP BY in one single record

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, union

I'm working on SQL Server and I need help with a query.

This is the scenario.

I have two tables `Forecast` and `Orders`.

There are some fields that match on both tables and other fields don't match.

It doesn't matter I can have all of them on a `SELECT`.

However, there are just 2 fields that should always match. `ID` and `SKU`.

At first I tried to use a `LEFT JOIN` but this doesn't work because I need one single column for `ID` and `SKU`.

Then I tried to `UNION` both tables and group by them.

Here are the code for `CREATE` and `INSERT`.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tbl_Forecast_Test](
[ID] [varchar](100) NULL,
[CUST_ID] [varchar](40) NULL,
[MFG_PART_NUMBER] [varchar](40) NULL,
[SEGMENT] [varchar](40) NULL,
[WH_NUMBER] [varchar](40) NULL,
[RTM] [varchar](40) NULL,
[FORECAST] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tbl_Orders_Test](
[ID] [varchar](100) NULL,
[END_CUST_ID] [varchar](40) NULL,
[PROD_ID] [varchar](40) NULL,
[PIPELINE] [varchar](40) NULL,
[WAREHOUSE] [varchar](40) NULL,
[RTM_GROUP] [varchar](40) NULL,
[ORDERS] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO [BOSSTest].[dbo].[Tbl_Forecast_Test]
([ID],[CUST_ID],[MFG_PART_NUMBER],[SEGMENT],[WH_NUMBER],[RTM],[FORECAST])
VALUES
('US8098629','','W0P88EP','Comm','471','Direct','10')

INSERT INTO [BOSSTest].[dbo].[Tbl_Orders_Test]
([ID],[END_CUST_ID],[PROD_ID],[PIPELINE],[WAREHOUSE],[RTM_GROUP],[ORDERS])
SELECT 'US8098629','W17445','W0P88EP','Ent Group','1','Direct','5'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'US8098629','W17445','V9G85EP','Ent Group','460','Direct','12'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'US8098629','W17445','V9G85EP','Ent Group','460','Direct','29'
```

This is the close that I get.

```
 SELECT  

 [ID]
,[CUST_ID]
,[END_CUST_ID]
,[SKU]
,[SEGMENT]
,[PIPELINE]
,[WH_NUMBER]
,[WAREHOUSE]
,[RTM] 
,[RTM_GROUP]
,SUM ([FORECAST]) AS [FORECAST]
,SUM([ORDERS]) AS [ORDER_LOAD]

FROM ( 

     SELECT  

     [ID] AS [ID]
    ,[CUST_ID]
    ,'' AS [END_CUST_ID]
    ,[MFG_PART_NUMBER] AS [SKU]
    ,[SEGMENT]
    ,'' AS [PIPELINE]
    ,[WH_NUMBER]
    ,'' AS [WAREHOUSE]
    ,[RTM] 
    ,'' AS [RTM_GROUP]
    ,SUM ([FORECAST]) AS [FORECAST]
    ,0 AS [ORDERS]

    FROM [BOSSTest].[dbo].[Tbl_Forecast_Test] 

    GROUP BY
     [ID]
    ,[CUST_ID]
    ,[MFG_PART_NUMBER]
    ,[SEGMENT]
    ,[WH_NUMBER]
    ,[RTM] 

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 

    [ID] AS [ID]
    ,'' AS [CUST_ID]
    ,[END_CUST_ID]
    ,[PROD_ID] AS [SKU]
    ,'' AS [SEGMENT]
    ,[PIPELINE]
    ,'' AS [WH_NUMBER]
    ,[WAREHOUSE]
    ,'' AS [RTM]
    ,[RTM_GROUP]
    ,0 AS [FORECAST]
    ,SUM([ORDERS]) AS [ORDERS]

    FROM [BOSSTest].[dbo].[Tbl_Orders_Test] 

    GROUP BY
     [ID]
    ,[END_CUST_ID]
    ,[PROD_ID] 
    ,[PIPELINE]
    ,[WAREHOUSE]
    ,[RTM_GROUP]


) AS TEST

GROUP BY
 [ID]
,[CUST_ID]
,[END_CUST_ID]
,[SKU]
,[SEGMENT]
,[PIPELINE]
,[WH_NUMBER]
,[WAREHOUSE]
,[RTM] 
,[RTM_GROUP]
```

This is the result when I execute the query.

```
+---------+-------+-----------+-------+-------+---------+---------+---------+------+---------+--------+----------+
|    ID   |CUST_ID|END_CUST_ID|SKU    |SEGMENT|PIPELINE |WH_NUMBER|WAREHOUSE| RTM  |RTM_GROUP|FORECAST|ORDER_LOAD|
+---------+-------+-----------+-------+-------+---------+---------+---------+------+---------+--------+----------+
|US8098629|       |           |W0P88EP| Comm  |         |   471   |         |Direct|         |      10|         0|
|US8098629|       | W17445    |V9G85EP|       |Ent Group|         |      460|      |   Direct|       0|        41|
|US8098629|       | W17445    |W0P88EP|       |Ent Group|         |        1|      |   Direct|       0|         5|
+---------+-------+-----------+-------+-------+---------+---------+---------+------+---------+--------+----------+
```

But this is what I need. I want to keep the different SKUs in the table.

```
+---------+-------+-----------+-------+-------+---------+---------+---------+------+---------+--------+----------+
|    ID   |CUST_ID|END_CUST_ID|SKU    |SEGMENT|PIPELINE |WH_NUMBER|WAREHOUSE| RTM  |RTM_GROUP|FORECAST|ORDER_LOAD|
+---------+-------+-----------+-------+-------+---------+---------+---------+------+---------+--------+----------+
|US8098629|       | W17445    |W0P88EP| Comm  |Ent Group|   471   |        1|Direct|   Direct|      10|         5|
|US8098629|       | W17445    |V9G85EP|       |Ent Group|         |      460|      |   Direct|       0|        41|
+---------+-------+-----------+-------+-------+---------+---------+---------+------+---------+--------+----------+
```

Any suggestion on how can I group `ID = US8098629` and `SKU = W0P88EP` in one single record.

Thanks in advance,
Luis

Comment: use MAX() on every field except ID and SKU, and group by ID and SKU. But your problem likely runs deeper than what you are stating.

Comment: What are your thoughts on this? Why do you think is deeper that what it seems?

Comment: What i mean is that you are likely going to run into issues as any aggregation method on Orders, Forecast, etc is used on larger datasets. Maybe not, but it's likely that you will. Any aggregation on a non numerical type is just used to get the a non-null value... but if there are two, then what? These are the likely problems you could run into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You stated you couldn't use a left join because you needed a single column for both ID and SKU.

With this in mind, you should still be able to use a left join. You don't have to select every column from both tables after performing the join. Include or omit columns as needed for your requirements.

```
SELECT ot.ID, ft.CUST_ID, ot.END_CUST_ID, ot.PROD_ID AS SKU, ft.SEGMENT,
       ot.PIPELINE, ft.WH_NUMBER, ot.WAREHOUSE, ft.RTM, ot.RTM_GROUP,
       SUM(ft.FORECAST) AS FORECAST, SUM(ot.ORDERS) AS ORDERS
FROM Tbl_Orders_Test ot
LEFT JOIN Tbl_Forecast_Test ft ON ft.ID = ot.ID AND ft.MFG_PART_NUMBER = ot.PROD_ID
GROUP BY ot.ID, ft.CUST_ID, ot.END_CUST_ID, ot.PROD_ID, ft.SEGMENT,
         ot.PIPELINE, ft.WH_NUMBER, ot.WAREHOUSE, ft.RTM, ot.RTM_GROUP
```

Comment: It works for group by one single record, but it seems that is excluding the other record with `SKU = V9G85EP` . I want to keep the different SKUs in the table.

Comment: @LuisLara That's because the second SKU doesn't appear in Tbl_Forecast_Test. I've updated my answer, simply reversing the join will retrieve both records. If you prefer empty strings over the NULLs you can use ISNULL in the select to fix.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below solution ,

```
       SELECT   [ID],[CUST_ID],max([END_CUST_ID]),[SKU],max([SEGMENT]),max([PIPELINE]),max([WH_NUMBER]),max([WAREHOUSE]),max([RTM]) ,max([RTM_GROUP]),SUM ([FORECAST]) AS [FORECAST],SUM([ORDERS]) AS [ORDER_LOAD]

 FROM ( 
 SELECT  

 [ID] AS [ID]    ,[CUST_ID]    ,'' AS [END_CUST_ID]    ,[MFG_PART_NUMBER] AS [SKU]    ,[SEGMENT]    ,'' AS [PIPELINE]    ,[WH_NUMBER]    ,'' AS [WAREHOUSE]
,[RTM]     ,'' AS [RTM_GROUP]    ,SUM ([FORECAST]) AS [FORECAST]    ,0 AS [ORDERS]
FROM [##Tbl_Forecast_Test] 

GROUP BY      [ID]   ,[CUST_ID]    ,[MFG_PART_NUMBER]    ,[SEGMENT]    ,[WH_NUMBER]    ,[RTM] 
UNION ALL

SELECT      [ID] AS [ID]    ,'' AS [CUST_ID]    ,[END_CUST_ID]    ,[PROD_ID] AS [SKU]    ,'' AS [SEGMENT]    ,[PIPELINE]    ,'' AS [WH_NUMBER]    ,[WAREHOUSE]
,'' AS [RTM]    ,[RTM_GROUP]    ,0 AS [FORECAST]    ,SUM([ORDERS]) AS [ORDERS]
    FROM [##Tbl_Orders_Test] 

   GROUP BY
 [ID]    ,[END_CUST_ID]    ,[PROD_ID]     ,[PIPELINE]    ,[WAREHOUSE]    ,[RTM_GROUP]) AS TEST
  GROUP BY
  [ID],[CUST_ID],[SKU]
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT  #Tbl_Orders_Test.[ID],ISNULL([CUST_ID],'') [CUST_ID],[END_CUST_ID],PROD_ID] [SKU],ISNULL([SEGMENT],'') [SEGMENT],[PIPELINE],ISNULL([WH_NUMBER],'') [WH_NUMBER],[WAREHOUSE],ISNULL([RTM],'')[RTM],[RTM_GROUP],ISNULL(SUM ([FORECAST]),0) AS [FORECAST],SUM([ORDERS]) AS [ORDER_LOAD] FROM #Tbl_Orders_Test LEFT OUTER JOIN #Tbl_Forecast_Test ON #Tbl_Forecast_Test.[ID] = #Tbl_Orders_Test.[ID] AND #Tbl_Forecast_Test [MFG_PART_NUMBER] = #Tbl_Orders_Test.[PROD_ID] GROUP BY #Tbl_Orders_Test.[ID],[CUST_ID],[END_CUST_ID],[PROD_ID] ,[SEGMENT],[PIPELINE],[WH_NUMBER],[WAREHOUSE],[RTM] ,[RTM_GROUP] ORDER BY [FORECAST] DESC

Answer (score -1):

At first glance it looks like you could stop grouping by "END_CUST_ID", and instead pull the first.

```
SELECT  
     [ID]
    ,[CUST_ID]
    ,Max([END_CUST_ID]) as [END_CUSTID]
    ,[SKU]
    ,[SEGMENT]
    ,[PIPELINE]
    ,[WH_NUMBER]
    ,[WAREHOUSE]
    ,[RTM] 
    ,[RTM_GROUP]
    ,SUM ([FORECAST]) AS [FORECAST]
    ,SUM([ORDERS]) AS [ORDER_LOAD]

    FROM ( 

         SELECT  

         [ID] AS [ID]
        ,[CUST_ID]
        ,'' AS [END_CUST_ID]
        ,[MFG_PART_NUMBER] AS [SKU]
        ,[SEGMENT]
        ,'' AS [PIPELINE]
        ,[WH_NUMBER]
        ,'' AS [WAREHOUSE]
        ,[RTM] 
        ,'' AS [RTM_GROUP]
        ,SUM ([FORECAST]) AS [FORECAST]
        ,0 AS [ORDERS]

        FROM [BOSSTest].[dbo].[Tbl_Forecast_Test] 

        GROUP BY
         [ID]
        ,[CUST_ID]
        ,[MFG_PART_NUMBER]
        ,[SEGMENT]
        ,[WH_NUMBER]
        ,[RTM] 

        UNION ALL

        SELECT 

        [ID] AS [ID]
        ,'' AS [CUST_ID]
        ,[END_CUST_ID]
        ,[PROD_ID] AS [SKU]
        ,'' AS [SEGMENT]
        ,[PIPELINE]
        ,'' AS [WH_NUMBER]
        ,[WAREHOUSE]
        ,'' AS [RTM]
        ,[RTM_GROUP]
        ,0 AS [FORECAST]
        ,SUM([ORDERS]) AS [ORDERS]

        FROM [BOSSTest].[dbo].[Tbl_Orders_Test] 

        GROUP BY
         [ID]
        ,[END_CUST_ID]
        ,[PROD_ID] 
        ,[PIPELINE]
        ,[WAREHOUSE]
        ,[RTM_GROUP]

    ) AS TEST

    GROUP BY
     [ID]
    ,[CUST_ID]
    ,[SKU]
    ,[SEGMENT]
    ,[PIPELINE]
    ,[WH_NUMBER]
    ,[WAREHOUSE]
    ,[RTM] 
    ,[RTM_GROUP]
```

Comment: FIRST isn't a function in SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks! Max() should work fine. I'll update my solution.

Comment: You've included all the unique values in your final group by(SEGMENT, PIPELINE, etc.), you're going to get three records back.